# iOS Nested / hierarchical data

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm new to iOS development (using swift). I have followed a couple of tutorials and can get a tableview to show data and then select a row and then show it in more details.

I was wondering how I would do the same but with data that is nested and not all elements have the same depth. I'm not sure how best to handle multiple layers of data before showing the details of the final element.

I have googled and can't seem to find any tutorials on this. Canal gone offer some suggestions ?

Cheers

James

Comment: How is the data nested, what is the nature of the data? You could add section headers to the table view to separate the cells.

Comment: Just use a table view where each cell is another table view. Calculate the height of each cell recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a basic dictionary to hold all your data or you could make a custom swift class to hold the data you need then create a custom tableView cell to display the nested data within your class. If you make custom Swift classes then they should be able to hold other custom Swift classes you made therefore accomplishing the nested data you need.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Good luck!